# Flutter: How to open gallery for both image and video

Tags: flutter, image, video, camera

I use camera package to open camera and take both video and image by one screen

in the past I used image_picker but it's satisfy my requirments for use camera and gallery to both video and image
so now I want the right way to open the gallery with both videos and images

how i can do it with camera package or otherwise?

Comment: Why isn't image_picker good? I use it to take pictures, pick images and videos from gallery and it works great. What problem is it that you are facing?

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin I want do every thing by one screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file_picker` (https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) package, which allows to select file with any extension.

Sample Code : -

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  type: FileType.custom,
  allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'pdf', 'doc'],
);
```

Complete Code : -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(const Example());

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  openExplorer() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'pdf', 'doc'],
    );
    if (result != null) {
      print("File selected");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: GestureDetector(
              onTap: (() {
                openExplorer();
              }),
              child: const Center(child: Text("Open Gallery")))),
    );
  }
}
```

Output : -

[image]

Comment: but I want open gallery not file manager

Comment: @AmerAlHajAli, as of now you can only open file manager but user can navigate to gallery. You can try gallery_picker (https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_picker) , gallery_media_picker(https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_media_picker)